# Writing ActiveX control in C# and add it to another C# project

Tags: c#, controls, activex, typelib

I need to create an ActiveX control and use it in another C# or old MFC project.
I followed the instructions I read here and in:
http://haseebakhtar.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/
and
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38890-activex-with-c%23/
And created an ActiveX.
First I have used the VS6 ActiveX tester and only after adding the "Control" key in the registry it appeared in the list of available ActiveX controls and I was able to use it.
Now I have 2 problems.
1. When I register it using regasm I get this message:

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.
>
> RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with
>   /codebase can ca use your assembly to interfere with other
>   applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase
>   switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give
>   your assembly a strong name and re-register it. Types registered
>   successfully Assembly exported to
>   'C:\Projects\TestOCX\TestOCX\bin\Release\TestOC X.tlb', and the type
>   library was registered successfully

When I register not using /codebase option I get no errors but I'm not sure why this happens.

Second when I try to add it to a new C# project I get a message that self registration has failed.
Anyone has a clue why this happens?

Comment: Please tell, did you make sure your ActiveX control assembly is given a strong name - as it is described in [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx) from MSDN?